# How to change the grid size in an RLQ plot?

Tags: r, plot

I need your help with this one. I'm trying to plot the results from an RLQ analysis in the following way:

```
par(mfrow = c(2, 2))
s.arrow(rlq_tra$l1)
s.arrow(rlq_tra$c1)
s.label(rlq_tra$lQ, boxes = FALSE)
s.label(rlq_tra$lR, boxes = FALSE)
```

and I obtain the following
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kbc2W.png)

Now, a professor of mine suggested that this image would be clearer if the size of the cells was the same in all the four plots. I'm not convinced that this will lead to a clearer image but I still want to try it. The only problem is that I don't know how (if it's possible) to change the "d" value.

I tried to use the adegraphics package and kinda accomplished something by changhing the number of grid cells in the plot

```
a<-s.arrow(rlq_tra_3$l1, pgrid.nint=1)
b<-s.arrow(rlq_tra_3$c1, pgrid.nint=2)
c<-s.label(rlq_tra_3$lQ, plabels.boxes.alpha=0, ppoints.alpha=0, pgrid.nint=6,)
d<-s.label(rlq_tra_3$lR, plabels.boxes.alpha=0, ppoints.alpha=0, pgrid.nint=6)

ADEgS(list(a,b,c,d), layout=c(2,2))
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I3jXQ.png)

but as you can see this didn't work as I expected. d is 1 in all the plots but the two top plots are absolutely abismal. Also I don't understand why the two plot-columns are so spaced, does someone know how to reduce that spacing?
Is there a way to change "d" without ridicolously zooming on the plots as I did?
Here there is what should be a reproducible example that leads to the same situation:

```
library(ade4)
library(adegraphics)
data(aravo)

veg_coa<-dudi.coa(aravo$spe, scannf=FALSE, nf=2)
tra_pca<-dudi.pca(aravo$traits, scannf=FALSE, row.w=veg_coa$cw)
suo_pca<-dudi.hillsmith(aravo$env, scannf=FALSE, row.w=veg_coa$lw) 

rlq_tra<-rlq(suo_pca, veg_coa, tra_pca, scannf=FALSE)

par(mfrow = c(2, 2))
ade4::s.arrow(rlq_tra$l1)
ade4::s.arrow(rlq_tra$c1)
ade4::s.label(rlq_tra$lQ, boxes = FALSE)
ade4::s.label(rlq_tra$lR, boxes=FALSE)

a<-s.arrow(rlq_tra$l1, pgrid.nint=1)
b<-s.arrow(rlq_tra$c1, pgrid.nint=2)
c<-s.label(rlq_tra$lQ, plabels.boxes.alpha=0, ppoints.alpha=0, pgrid.nint=6,)
d<-s.label(rlq_tra$lR, plabels.boxes.alpha=0, ppoints.alpha=0, pgrid.nint=6)

ADEgS(list(a,b,c,d), layout=c(2,2))
```

Thank you in advance!!

Comment: Could you please share some reproducible data using `dput`?

Comment: I should have added a reproducible example that leads to the same plots